# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am writing simple application to be familiar with spring batch. I wanted to learn spring batch admin but I found that it is deprecated so I have to use spring cloud data flow instead.

I've found a tutorial about spring cloud data and did first steps:

1. Added dependency:

   compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local:1.7.4.RELEASE")
2. And marked my spring boot application class with additioanl annotaion:

   @EnableDataFlowServer

Now I am trying to run it using idea but it prints:

```
10:24:09.590 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:340)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at spring.boot.hello.world.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases this is either due to a missing dependency or due to a dependency coming with an older spring/spring boot version.
Check your maven dependency tree and search for spring-boot dependencies older then the version your parent starter is requesting. Probably `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local:1.7.4.RELEASE` comes with an older version and you need to exclude it.

Comment: Looks like BOM doesn't contain version of spring cloud data flow

Comment: Which version of spring boot starter parent do you use?

Comment: I use 2.1.6.RELEASE